# (CSS) Click Menu/Dropdown with Changing Divs

Tags: html, css, menu, click

I don't know any java and I'm just getting into html/css. I've been looking all over google...getting a lot of partial examples but I don't know how to make them all work together. I want to click on an image I'm using as a button and have 2 list items show. Both of those list items has 3 sub-list items and each of the sub-lists has 5 items. I know the html, but I can't seems to design it how I need to. Here's what I want:

When I clickMe, House1 and House2 drop down.

Then, if I choose House1, House2 disappears and only House1's three lists will show.

From there, if I choose BackYard, I want FrontYard and Side to disappear, only showing BackYard's five items.

After looking this over, I can see how confusing this could seem. I'm trying to draw something up in Paint, will update the post later lol. The closest I got to what I wanted was using details/summary method, but I couldn't get display:none to work and I couldn't get rid of the black arrows on each detail tag.

Edit: Here's what i have in details/summary method. Please excuse the sloppy spacing and such...
http://jsfiddle.net/New2Code/ap1s3hto/

When I click on Area 1 > East, i want everything to hide except Area 1, East, and its 5 thumbnails in the center. The way it is now, West and Central slide to the side and Area 2 still shows at the bottom.

```
<ul id="clickMe"><img src="buttonPic"/>



<li>House1
    <ul>
        <li>FrontYard
            <ul>
                <li>Stuff1</li>
                <li>Stuff2</li>
                <li>Stuff3</li>
                <li>Stuff4</li>
                <li>Stuff5</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>BackYard
            <ul>
                <li>Stuff1</li>
                <li>Stuff2</li>
                <li>Stuff3</li>
                <li>Stuff4</li>
                <li>Stuff5</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Side
            <ul>
                <li>Stuff1</li>
                <li>Stuff2</li>
                <li>Stuff3</li>
                <li>Stuff4</li>
                <li>Stuff5</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
   </ul>
</li>






<li>House2
<ul>
        <li>FrontYard
            <ul>
                <li>Stuff1</li>
                <li>Stuff2</li>
                <li>Stuff3</li>
                <li>Stuff4</li>
                <li>Stuff5</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>BackYard
            <ul>
                <li>Stuff1</li>
                <li>Stuff2</li>
                <li>Stuff3</li>
                <li>Stuff4</li>
                <li>Stuff5</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Side
            <ul>
                <li>Stuff1</li>
                <li>Stuff2</li>
                <li>Stuff3</li>
                <li>Stuff4</li>
                <li>Stuff5</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
   </ul></li>
```

Comment: `<img>` cannot be a direct descendant of `<ul>`. Only `<li>` can.

Comment: (OT) The way you're trying to do it seems pretty odd and not the way a drop-down *tree-menu* UI should work. Makes no sense to show some items collapsed, but close them once another is selected... there's no meaningful logic (**if I've got your Q right**).

Comment: Also what you need is not ***Java*** but [***JavaScript***](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-_VPez8O2x0k/UNpD2TvVM2I/AAAAAAAAAeQ/CKceQdG7K84/w506-h380/This-is-javascript.png) and I'd suggest you to use **jQuery** for ease of DOM elements manipulation. Also you should try to post what you've tried in resolving your own issue. *"Do it for me"* is not an expected question here on SO.

Comment: Updated with what I have. I'm sorry if I made it sound like a 'do it for me' situation. I'm really just having trouble with the animation and hide/show. Also those black arrows on the side (they only disappear in Chrome, firefox and safari shows them)